# @Url.Action no funciona en archivo javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvc

Desde una vista `razor` puedo hacer llamado a links con esto

```
window.location = '@Url.Action("ReporteDictaminaciones", "Auditoria")' + '?Auditor=' + auditor
```

Al pasarlo a un archivo JavaScript deja de funcionar.

¿Alguna Solución?

Comment: y con toda la razón no va a funcionar... la sintaxis Razor funciona con archivos .CSHTML no con archivos .js

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no hay problema: usar sintaxis razor en archivos .JS no funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución (no es la más preciosa) sería guardar el contenido en una variable dentro de la vista y luego usarla en el archivo js.

Código en la vista:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myURL = '@Url.Action("ReporteDictaminaciones", "Auditoria")' + '? Auditor=' + auditor;
</script>
```

Código en archivo js:

```
function () {
   alert(myURL);
}
```

La contra de esto es que tenes que definir esta variable en todas las vistas que usen el archivo js (o la función en cuestión).